# Passing selected item data to controller from Multilevel dropdown

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, .net-core, model-view-controller

I have created a multilevel dropdown which is dynamic. **When I am clicking the third level item(new, in progress, resolved which are from the database)it should be selected and only when I am clicking the create button that selected item data should be passed to the controller**.

***multilevel dropdown code***

```
 <div class="dropdown drop">
            <button class="btn  dropdown-toggle"
                    type="button"
                    id="dropdownMenuButton"
                    data-mdb-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                STATUS
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">

                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                        ProjectStatus &raquo;
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu">
                        @foreach (var i in ViewBag.ProjectStatus)
                        {
                        <li>
                            @*<a id="ProjectStatus" class="dropdown-item" href="#">@i.Text</a>*@
                            <select asp-for="ProjectStatus" class="form-control" value="@i.Text">@i.Text</select>
                        </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                        DevelopmentStatus &raquo;
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu">
                        @foreach (var i in ViewBag.DevelopmentStatus)
                        {
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">@i.Text</a>
                        </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**HttpGet create method**

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.ProjectStatus = new SelectList(_context.ProjectStatus, "ProjectStatusID", "Status");
    ViewBag.DevelopmentStatus = new SelectList(_context.DevelopmentStatus, "DevelopmentStatusID", "Status");
    return View();
}
```

*Need to get the selected list item data to the post method*

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Projects ec) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put the selected item value to a hidden input,and then change the background of the `<li></li>`.Here is a demo:

```
    <div class="dropdown drop">
        <button class="btn  dropdown-toggle"
                type="button"
                id="dropdownMenuButton"
                data-mdb-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false">
            STATUS
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    ProjectStatus &raquo;
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu">
                    @foreach (var i in ViewBag.ProjectStatus)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href='#' onclick='return change("@i.Text",this,"ProjectStatus")'>@i.Text</a>
                        </li>
                    }
    
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                    DevelopmentStatus &raquo;
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu">
                    @foreach (var i in ViewBag.DevelopmentStatus)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href='#' onclick='return change("@i.Text",this,"DevelopmentStatus")'>@i.Text</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input id="ProjectStatus" name="ProjectStatus" hidden />
    <input id="DevelopmentStatus" name="DevelopmentStatus" hidden />
<script>
    function change(text, t, type) {
        $("li").css("background", "transparent");
        if (type == "ProjectStatus") {
            $("#ProjectStatus").val(text);
            $("#DevelopmentStatus").val("");
        } else {
            $("#DevelopmentStatus").val(text);
            $("#ProjectStatus").val("");
        }
        $(t).parent().css("background", "#1266f1");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

When select ProjectStatus,the selected value will be put to `$("#ProjectStatus")`,and the value of `$("#DevelopmentStatus")` will be `""`.When select DevelopmentStatus,the selected value will be put to `$("#DevelopmentStatus")`,and the value of `$("#ProjectStatus")` will be `""`.

result:
[image]

Comment: this is working , but only one data is transferring to the controller , either project status or development status . And also you give the code for the multilevel for me it's taking a long time to load the scree now (I think because of those links you provided) can you make that drop down without those links , so that the page will load faster. And this multilevel drop down is not working in debug mode , so I can't find the error in it. Kindly look into these issues . Thank you..

Comment: Firstly,only the value of hidden input with correct name will be binded.If you want to bind other data,you need to create other inputs,and you didn't show your model Projects  or the data you want to bind.And then the links make sure you can use the multilevel which is said in the official [doc](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/getting-started/installation/).

Comment: Thanks a lot... the issue was you make an input null when selecting one , actually I need both of those inputs. I have corrected it .